# SVN don't watch dir for changes (but still keep in repo)

Tags: svn, file-management

I have a project that requires a certain directory and all the files in it to build properly.

```
trunk/
    stuff1/
    stuff2/
    build_requirements/
        [a whole lot of stuff...]
```

The `trunk/build_requirements` *must* be checked out with the code. If it is not present, the build will not work. However, the contents of `build_requirements` will never, ever change. It's also huge, and checking for changes in it slows down commits. I also don't want people to accidentally be able to commit changes to it.

I don't think ignore will work. When someone checks out the project, they need to get everything in `build_requirements/`, and adding it to the ignore list would prevent that.

Does SVN has an appropriate way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for externals. Probably you should have your `build_requirements` live somewhere outside of your development branch in your repo. You can tag a version of it and include that tag in your SVN externals for `trunk`. That way, when you check out trunk, you will get your tagged `build_requirements` but committing changes to `trunk` will not result in changes being committed to `build_requirements`.

A person still could commit changes to `build_requirements` (that is the point of SVN after all), but it would be much harder to do accidentally. He would have to specifically be checking that in. Committing to `trunk` will not cause any changes to `build_requirements` to be committed.